# Explicit conversion to enum in c#

Tags: c#, enums, clr

How does CLR determine which Color zero should be converted to?

```
internal static class Test
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine((Color)0);
    }

    private enum Color
    {
        Red,
        Green = Red
    }
}
```

Using this Color's definition "Red" will be outputted.

If we use other definitions, results are really very interesting.

```
private enum Color
{
    Red,
    Green = Red,
    Blue = Red,
    Yellow = Red
}
```

The output is "Green".

Another definition:

```
private enum Color
{
    Red,
    Green = Red,
    Blue,
    Yellow  = Red
}
```

The output is "Yellow".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It just returns a `Color` value with an underlying value of 0. That's the same value as `Color.Red` and `Color.Green`.

Fundamentally, your enum is broken in that `Red` and `Green` are the same value. You can't distinguish between them at all.

```
Color red = Color.Red;
Color green = Color.Green;
Console.WriteLine(red == green); // True
Console.WriteLine(red.ToString() == green.ToString()); // True
```

I don't know if there are any guarantees around whether `ToString` returns "Red" or "Green" - but if you get to the situation where that's relevant, you should have described your enum differently.

EDIT: From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z.aspx):

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make any assumptions about which name the method will return. For example, the following enumeration defines two members, Shade.Gray and Shade.Grey, that have the same underlying value.
>
> ...
>
> The following method call attempts to retrieve the name of a member of the Shade enumeration whose underlying value is 1. The method can return either "Gray" or "Grey", and your code should not make any assumptions about which string will be returned.

Comment: I think, I would never face to the situation where this is really relevant, but the result of look-upping the corresponding Color is rather curiously in this intermezzo (see my updates).

Comment: @Dixon: See my edit. Basically, you're asking about what `ToString` does - and the docs say not to rely on any particular behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Each enum variable in .net map to integer value so from that only it get to know which type to return

[MSDN- enum (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
The default underlying type of the enumeration elements is int. By default, the
first enumerator has the value 0, and the value of each successive enumerator is 
 increased by 1.
```

Comment: I understand this. I don't quite understand how CLR defines which Color (see my examples) should be mapped to value 0.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for something like this is - undefined. You may find that the answer changes from version to version, or even machine to machine (less likely). While the question is interesting - you should NEVER rely on any particular answer being produced in a situation like this. There are plenty of other ways to go about that you are trying to do.

Like:

```
 private enum MainColor
    {
        Red,
        Green, 
        Blue, 
    }

   private enum Color
   {
        Red = MainColor.Red,
        Green = MainColor.Green, 
        Blue = MainColor.Blue, 
        Brown = MainColor.Red, 
   }
```

You can then cast back to MainColor and get a definitive answer.

It seems to me that it is coming up with an the first match it finds based on some kind of hashed list. The details should never matter to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your enum try this  :

```
    private enum Color
    {  
         Red,
         Green,BLUE,black,brown = Red,gray  
    }
```

Observations :

```
1) (Color)0 : Red  
2) (Color)1 : Green   
3) (Color)2 : BLUE  
4) (Color)3 : black
```

so CLR will take it in the order which they come in enum.

Comment: using your enum's definition ((Color)0).ToString() results in "brown", so the assumption about taking the first one Name defined don't seem to be true (look at my updates).